# Voltage & Current source , absorb or deliver the power?

Tags: power-supply

How to decide, given Voltage & Current source , absorb or deliver the power?

Answer (score 3):

When voltage and current are going in the *same* direction, the source is *delivering* power.

When voltage and current are going in *opposite* directions, the source is *absorbing* power.

Comment: If we consider that absorption=dissipation and deliver=generation, then in case of dissipation the power product should have plus(+) sign and in case of generation the power product sould have minus(-) sign, i.e. 8W is absorbed power and -8W is generated power.

Comment: @GRTech That's a bad assumption. A battery or a capacitor will absorb energy but have little dissipation. I think Ignacio's wording is precise.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany Thats why I upvote his unswer! My comment is to mention that the right sign for the generated power sould be negative. This resulting by the Ignacio's right definition.  Don't be vicious with me please.